# Invalid character found in the request target on Confluence behind nginx

Tags: nginx, confluence

Currently I'm using Confluence 6.10.2 behind nginx. I have some pages with the page name including character '>' could not accessible, the error is:

> HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request Type Exception Report
>
> Message Invalid character found in the request target. The valid
>   characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
>
> Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to
>   something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed
>   request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request
>   routing).
>
> Exception
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the
>   request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC
>   3986
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:474)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:294)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:764)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1388)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Note The full stack trace of
>   the root cause is available in the server logs.
>
> Apache Tomcat/9.0.10

But when I access the page bypassing the reverse proxy, it's OK, so it could be a problem in nginx.

I read logs in Confluence and nginx, but did not find anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: For a lot of practical reasons, I would strongly discourage use of character such as ">" in file names, as most interactions with command line tools are likely to get confused.

Comment: I think in nginx configuration must have some rewrite rule to by pass this issue

Answer (score 0):

Probably you'll need to add a rewrite rule.

- [Nginx Rewrite to Replace a single Character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43597569/nginx-rewrite-to-replace-single-character)
- [Nginx Doc - Creating Rewrite Rules](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)

```html
if ($request_uri ~ ^(/.*)[>](.*)$) { 
    return 301 $1%3E$2;
}
if ($request_uri ~ ^(/.*)[<](.*)$) { 
    return 301 $1%3C$2;
}
```

You may want to place this inside a `location` block to limit the scope. See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but no luck. I just found out that, the request has been drop from nginx, it not even go go confluence upstream.